# Implementing an event and periodically driven "script language" in C++?

Tags: c++, architecture, mpi

**Background:**
I want to create an automation framework in C++ where on the one hand "sensors" and "actors" and on the other "logic engines" can be connected to a "core".
The "sensors" and "actors" might be connected to the machine running the "core", but some might also be accessible via a field bus or via normal computer network. Some might work continuous or periodically (e.g. every 100 milliseconds a new value), others might work event driven (e.g. only when a switch is [de]activated a message will come with the new state).
The "logic engine" would be sort of pluggable into the core and e.g. consist out of embedded well known script languages (Perl, Python, Lua, ...). There will run different little scripts from the users that can subscribe to "sensors" and write to "actors".
The "core" would route the sensor/actor informations to the subscribed scripts and call them. Some just after the event occurred, others periodically as defined in a scheduler.

**Additional requirements:**

- The systems ("server") running this automation application might also be quite
  small (500MHz x86 and 256 MB RAM) or if possible even tiny (OpenWRT
  based router) as power consumption is an issue
  => efficiency is important
  => multicore support not for the moment, but I'm sure it'll become important soon - so the design has to support it
- Some sort of fail save mode has to be possible, e.g. two systems monitoring each other
- application / framework will be GPL => all used libraries have to be compatible
- the server would run Linux, but cross platform would be nice

**The big question:**
What is the best architecture for such a kind of application / framework?

**My reasoning:**
Not to reinvent the wheel I was wondering to use MPI to do all the event handling.
This would allow me to focus on the relevant stuff and not on the message handling, especially when two or more "servers" would work together (watchdog for each other as well as each having a few sensors and actors connected). Each sensor and actor handler as well as the logic engines themself would only be required to implement a predefined MPI based interface and thus be crash save. The core could restart each when it's not responsive anymore.

**The additional questions:**

- Would that be even possible with MPI? (It'd be used a bit out of context...)
- Would the overhead of MPI be too big? Should I just write it myself using sockets and threads?
- Are there other libraries possible that are better suited in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to construct your system using MPI, but I think MPI is too much focused on high performance computing. Moreover, since it was designed for C, it does not really fit the object oriented way of programming very much. IMO there are other approaches better suited for your needs:

- [Boost ASIO](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) might be a good fit for designing your system. It includes both network functionality and helps at event-driven programming (which could be a good way to design your system). You can have a look at [Think-Async](http://blog.think-async.com/) webpage for some examples on using ASIO for event-driven programming.
- You could also use plain threads and borrow the network capabilities from ASIO (without using the event-driven programming parts). If you can use C++11, then you can directly use `std::thread` and all the other functionality available (mutex, conditional variables, futures, etc.). If you cannot use C++11, you can always use [Boost Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/thread.html).
- Finally, if you really want to go for MPI, you can have a look at [Boost MPI](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/mpi.html). At least you will have a much more C++ friendly way of using MPI.

Comment: Although I didn't research the different MPI possibilities yet, Boost MPI was definitely on the list of the for me interesting implementations.   
Did I understand that correctly that MPI is only an API but not an protocoll, i.e. different implementations don't work together? (And one exception of that rule is Boost MPI as it could interface Python?)

Comment: @Chris I have only used mpich2 and OpenMPI. I am not 100% sure, but I do not think you can use multiple versions. I have only used MPI during my Master's courses, so I am not too much familiar with it. But IMO the whole MPI model does not really seems to fit what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I finally decided against MPI and am trying my luck with ZeroMQ.